# Getting List<String> in hibernate from database

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have two tables `bo_operator` and `hist_bo_operator_password` with foreign key `id_operator bigint REFERENCES bo_operator(id)`.
In `hist_bo_operator_password` there are many password for one `id_operator`. Now I would like to take all that values into `List<String>` in spring boot application. 
So far I have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="bo_operator")
@SecondaryTable(name = "hist_bo_operator_password", pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id_operator", referencedColumnName="id"))
public class Operator {
    public Operator(Long id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }
```

How can I write method:

```
@Column(table="hist_bo_operator_password", name="password") 
public List<String> getOldPasswords()
{
    return  
}
```

to return all passwords from `hist_bo_operator_password` for `id_operator`?

Comment: I don't want new class just for one column in another table, especially when it's strongly connected with Operator. I would like to get this column into Operator class or is it breaking some rule that one table=one entity?

Comment: I don't think you can do this the way you did using `@SecondaryTable` since that's mostly used for "onetoone" relationships where the info of a single entity is spread amongst two tables. I think you need to use the `@ElementCollection` annotation as mentioned in the linked answer.

Comment: @ElementCollection
 @CollectionTable(name="hist_bo_operator_password", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_operator"))
 @Column(name="password")
 public List<String> oldPasswords = new ArrayList<String>();

solved a problem as it was mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

@ElementCollection lets you define a mapping for a non-Entity class ...or use @CollectionTable to define the table.